# Formatting currency digits with commas

Tags: java, currency-formatting

I am using a java webapp, In Java class i use a Remote server API to get values like  `48938493843894`.  I export these values to a .XLSX file.  I want to format this number like
`$48,938,493,843,894`  at the java class and export to .xlsx file.

How can i do this in Java?

Comment: Have you try `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`?
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()

Comment: Thanks, btw how to get rid of values after period  i.e.,  $54,666,700.00  i mean a direct method in api, instead of substring etc.,

Comment: `NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)` should work:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)  BTW. Remember that this solution is locale specific. So it maybe better to setup locale for formatter before using it.

Comment: Yes, it works.. Thanks. BTW how can accept your answer when its a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For formatting currency it's better to use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` (look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance) and for limiting fractional part there is `NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern `###,###.###` to format it.

```
        String str = "48938493843894";
        String pattern="###,###.###";
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        String output = myFormatter.format(Double.parseDouble(str));
        System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Currency formatter adds currency symbol where needed, which is depends on locale and for some currencies can be in front, like $100, or behind, like 100 (eurosign)